# What are the pointwise definable elements of this metric space structure?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R};d)$, where $d$ is the binary operation that takes two real numbers and gives the standard distance between them, that is, the absolute value of their difference. What are the pointwise definable elements of that structure? I conjecture that it is only $0$. Is this conjecture true?

Comment: Why would $0$ be definable?

Comment: @tomasz The OP is viewing $d$ as a binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$. So $0$ is defined by $\exists y\, (d(y,y) = x)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I presume "pointwise definable element" should be "parameter-freely-definable element" - pointwise-definability is a property of a given structure as a whole, namely that all of its elements are parameter-freely-definable, rather than any of that structure's specific elements.*

---

Yes. This can be shown by thinking about automorphisms; specifically, by determining the automorphism orbits of the structure in question, which is a technique that has been used to answer some of your questions in the past if I recall correctly.

The structure $(\mathbb{R},d)$ has exactly **three** automorphism orbits, namely $\{0\}$, the negative numbers, and the positive numbers (think about any map of the form $x\mapsto rx$ for $r$ fixed and positive). Since every parameter-freely-definable element must have a singleton orbit, we're done.

Comment: I'm confused. The metric is invariant, why would $0$ be fixed?

Comment: @tomasz $d$ is the map $d(x,y)=\vert x-y\vert$.